# Преобразовать строку в число? C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

Всем привет, есть textBox я с него получаю данные таким методом:
`String^S1 = textBox1->Text;`
Дальше чтобы перевести в число я использую `x = Convert::ToInt32(S2);`
Но у меня получается int`овское значение, и при вводе float я получаю ошибку, как конвертировать в тип float?

Comment: `Convert::ToSingle`. `float` является [псевдонимом](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0wf2yk2k.aspx) для `System.Single`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для парсинга чисел с плавающей точкой в .NET есть [Double::Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt(v=vs.110).aspx) и `TryParse`. Аналогично для `Single` (который синоним `float`)